# Meaning of Random forest parameter "keep.forest"

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

On the R package randomForest, what does the setting the parameter `keep.Forest` to True do?

```
library(randomForest)
rf_model <- randomForest(rf_train_data$revenue ~ ., data= train_merged, keep.forest=TRUE, ntree=30)
```

Comment: You need to specify the language and library you are using for anyone to help you. Also probably the answer is on the documentation of that library

Answer (score 0):

From the [RandomForest documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf):

> **keep.forest**:  If set to FALSE, the forest will not be retained in the
>   output object. If xtest is given, defaults to FALSE.